# ASP.NET webforms - saving viewstate to database - viewstate validation doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, viewstate

We have an ASP.NET 4.8 webforms application that saves the viewstate to database instead of sending it to the client. On postback, the viewstate is restored from the database via a hidden key field.

With this setup I have noticed that the usual viewstate validation doesn't happen anymore. I tried to trigger viewstate validation on postback by changing the viewstate value after it was loaded from the database and ASP.NET did not cause any exceptions.

Is this by design since the viewstate is stored now in the database and there's no way for any tampering of it on the client side?

Any comments would be appreciated.

Code for loading/saving viewstate (as per recommendation from asp.net community):

```
    public class DatabasePageStatePersister : PageStatePersisterBase
{

    private string VIEWSTATEKEY_HIDDENFIELDNAME => "viewstatekey";

    public DatabasePageStatePersister(Page page)
        : base(page)
    {
    }

    public override void Load()
    {
        var key = Page.Request.Form[VIEWSTATEKEY_HIDDENFIELDNAME];
        if (key != null)
        {

            var viewState = ViewStateDatabasePersistenceHelper.GetPageState(key);
            RestorePageState(viewState);


        }

    }

    public override void Save()
    {
        if (ViewState != null || ControlState != null)
        {

            var key = ViewStateDatabasePersistenceHelper.SavePageState(GetPageState());         
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField(VIEWSTATEKEY_HIDDENFIELDNAME, key);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's excerpt from my Page's base class which ALL pages derive from (this is a property on the System.Web.UI.Page class that gets invoked whenever the page is saving/loading viewstate):

```
    protected override PageStatePersister PageStatePersister
    {
        get
        {
            return ViewStatePersistence.GetViewStatePersister(this, AppCfg);
        }
    }
```

Clarifications:

PageStatePersisterBase derives from System.Web.UI.PageStatePersister and here's it's implementation:

```
public abstract class PageStatePersisterBase : PageStatePersister
{
    public PageStatePersisterBase(Page page)
        : base(page)
    {
    }

    protected virtual byte[] GetPageState()
    {
        // serialize view state
        Pair statePair = new Pair(ViewState, ControlState);
        IStateFormatter formatter = new ObjectStateFormatter();
        string viewState = formatter.Serialize(statePair);

        // compress view state
        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(viewState);
        return Deflate.Compress(bytes);
    }

    protected virtual void RestorePageState(byte[] bytes)
    {
        // decompress
        byte[] b = Deflate.Decompress(bytes);

        // deserialize
        IStateFormatter formatter = new ObjectStateFormatter();
        string viewState = Convert.ToBase64String(b);
        Pair statePair = (Pair)formatter.Deserialize(viewState);

        ViewState = statePair.First;
        ControlState = statePair.Second;
    }
```

ViewStatePersistence.GetViewStatePersister() simply creates an instance of DatabasePageStatePersister from my config file.

Comment: you need to post your code, how you save and retrieve viewstate. It is important WHEN you save and retrieve it. You supposed to overwrite some page methods as it can impact page lifecycle.

Comment: I have added the missing code sample. The viewstate is saved/loaded per page request during viewstate life cycle.

Comment: I have a suspicion that you are not saving /retrieving it at correct time. see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010490/when-to-save-a-variable-in-viewstate

Comment: I disagree, since my class simply implements PageStatePersisterBase, it is invoked by the framework during the correct time of the page life cycle.

Comment: possibly. I am just not sure how it gets invoked. You pass `page` into constructor. Does `base` wires it up? did you reflect it? Or you need to wire something?

Comment: Sorry, I was under the impression that PageStatePersisterBase was a framework class, instead it is one of our classes that derives from System.Web.UI.PageStatePersister; I updated my comments and added the implementation of this class and additional notes.

Comment: ViewStatePersistence.GetViewStatePersister() simply creates an instance of DatabasePageStatePersister from my config file.

Comment: then the question is, with custom viewstate, what is page declaration says, `EnableViewState = "false"`?

Comment: No, to your question. I can only conclude based on my logical understanding of the viewstate life cycle that if the view state is not in the hidden field on the client, there's no point of doing any viewstate validation since you have nothing to validate against, because viewstate is not passed around.

Comment: completely possible